# Make sprite in GameScene.sks and access it in code

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I was making an app in Sprite Kit and I didn't want to design my level in code so I used my GameScene.sks file and visually made my level and I named each of the nodes I made in the GameScene.sks. Now I want to access the nodes in my code that I added in GameScene.sks. How do I for example move a sprite that I made in GameScene.sks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you named the nodes, than you can access them within the scene by using

```
func childNodeWithName(_ name: String) -> SKNode?
```

Then you can apply e.g. an `SKAction` to the node.